# gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk3

I have GTK GUI where it has a control button that opens a new window called `c_window` in my struct. `c_window` has a quit button that I need to connect to the `c_quit` function. When I tried to do so the window is not terminated and a warning keeps appearing each time I pressed on quit button:

```
(main_menu:2682): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 06:30:38.469: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

my `c_quit` function is:

```c
    static gboolean c_quit (gpointer userData)
    {
    message_details *details = (message_details *)userData;
    gtk_widget_destroy (details->c_window); 
    return FALSE;
    }
```

how do I connect it from the main

```c
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(details->c_quit), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (c_quit),  details->c_window);
```

Please note that `details` is my struct where I define my `GtkWidget` elements.

Comment: You pass `details->c_windows` as user data, not `details`. Try `gtk_widget_destroy (userData);`

Comment: I tried it but only Quit button is disappeared when i click on Quit button

Comment: Then you have a second problem in your code. But as you don't show any relevant code, how would we know what you are doing wrong? We don't know what any of your variables hold, how you create the objects etc. Show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And as this is a different topic, please create a new post (with all the relevant code) for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your signal connection function is:

```c
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(details->c_quit), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (c_quit),  details->c_window);
```

Which contains an unnecessary cast for `details->c_quit`. Additionally, you're passing the `c_window` field of the `details` pointer.

Next, your callback is:

```c
static gboolean c_quit (gpointer userData)
{
  message_details *details = (message_details *)userData;
  gtk_widget_destroy (details->c_window); 
  return FALSE;
}
```

which has the wrong signature for a callback to the [`GtkButton::clicked` signal](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Button.clicked.html); the correct signature would be:

```c
static void
c_quit (GtkButton *button, gpointer data)
```

Additionally, I'd recommend using a proper function name for the callback, so you can easily understand what it does, and where it's referenced. For instance, something `quit_button__clicked`.

Inside your callback you're accessing the wrong parameter, with the wrong type:

```c
message_details *details = (message_details *)userData;
```

Because you're not passing the `details` data, you're passing a pointer to the window itself. Additionally, `gpointer` is an alias to `void*`, and C allows implicit casting to and from a `void*`; this means you don't need an explicit cast there.

So, to recap:

1. connect the signal properly, using the correct arguments to send to your callback:

```c
g_signal_connect (details->c_quit, "clicked",
                  G_CALLBACK (quit_button__clicked),
                  details);
```

2. use the right prototype for the signal you're connecting to, and access the right data:

```c
static void
quit_button__clicked (GtkButton *button G_GNUC_UNUSED,
                      gpointer user_data)
{
  message_details *details = user_data;
  gtk_widget_destroy (details->c_window);
}
```

If you just want to call `gtk_widget_destroy()` on the window widget in response to a `clicked` signal on a `GtkButton`, you can also condense everything into a single call:

```c
g_signal_connect_swapped (details->c_quit, "clicked",
                          G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy),
                          details->c_window);
```

The `g_signal_connect_swapped()` function will swap the first and last arguments of the signal when invoking the callback—the first argument being the instance that emitted the signal, and the last argument being the user data passed to connection function. This means that `gtk_widget_destroy()` will be called with the user data argument of `g_signal_connect_swapped()`.

Comment: SOLVED!!
you are right, I have updated my code as you recommend, now it is working properly thank you